# fun project i want to create a CEX

Tags: solidity, bsc, cpp-ethereum, binance-smart-chain, binance

hey i want to create a centralized exchange just for fun project and to understand how things works. Is there any good open source project and good docs for that please? Thank you !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.